# WPF Remove Margin Animation Programmatically

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard, stackpanel, margins

How do I remove the margins of two sides of a stackpanel in an animation storyboard so it looks like the stackpanel has moved from the code behind? I need to do it in the code-behind because the number of stackpanels i use this animation on differs at runtime. Thanks :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you're asking how to set the margin value in the code behind or in the animation XAML, so I'll take a shot at both.

In the code behind you can use the [DependencyProperty.SetValue method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473.aspx). For example: `stackPanel.SetValue(MarginProperty, 0);`

For the XAML animation you can add a thickness animation. For example:
`<ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="stackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
    <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.025" Value="4,4,2,2"/>
</ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>`